# PC speaker pops like if someone is calling, but is not. Is my phone hacked?

Tags: malware

I keep hearing sound pops on my PC speaker like if my phone was connected to the internet or if someone was calling, but it's nothing.

Is my phone hacked? Is it recording some surveillance audio records and then sending them online to someone?

The phone is Alcatel One Touch S'Pop

Comment: 'sound pops on your PC speaker'? Why would your phone in any way affect your computer's speakers?

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos A lot of speakers will pick up the signal from mobile phones, it sounds like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5ruAZ4Useg&t=21).  The existence of a signal has no connectiong to "hacking", however. OP, if you have an actually reason to suspect an issue please explain.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what the OP ment. Thanks, @MatthewRead

Comment: My internet would be disconnected and I'd hear the popping. Then, I'd move the phone around the speaker and the loudness of the popping changed with the proximity of the phone and the speaker which means that it's something about my phone.

Comment: @Foxcat385, did you try doing the same with your phone in airplane mode?

Answer (score 1):

Is your phone on Airplane Mode? If it's not, large cellular data packets will cause the same sound.

Shouldn't be anything bad, even ***if you specifically knew*** that your phone wasn't doing it before.

**Automatic updates** to Play Services and `ConfigUpdater` can change device behavior at any time, such as cellular radios (drivers).

It could also be a **new cell tower in the area** causing the change in behavior. Newer cell towers are taking advantage of the latest frequencies, so that could explain a change in behavior.

If your phone is on Airplane Mode, and the sounds are appearing, you might want to check your room (and nearby rooms) for other cell phones. If you have a reason to be worried, look for bugs also.